# Proxy SVN Google Code based maven repository in Sonatype Nexus

Tags: java, maven, repository, nexus, sonatype

I have set up the Sonatype Nexus for repository caching.

com.googlecode.htmleasy is not being resolved by maven. Getting error

> Failure to find com.googlecode.htmleasy:htmleasy:jar:0.7 in
>   `http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public` was cached in the
>   local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

htmleasy is one artifact which is sitting inside google code based maven repo.

```
 <repository>
      <id>htmleasy</id>
      <url>http://htmleasy-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/</url>
   </repository>
```

But What should I do so that when I refer following artifact based on above repo

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.htmleasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>htmleasy</artifactId>
      <version>0.7</version>
   </dependency>
```

gets resolved by my maven ?

My maven settings xml looks like as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <proxies></proxies>
  <servers></servers>
  <pluginGroups></pluginGroups>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Add a new proxy repository](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-new-repo.html) and do not forget to [add it to your 'public' repository group](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-repo-group.html).

(If you still get "resolution will no be reattempted" error from maven, try calling maven with '-U'.)

Comment: 1) I had already created and added the proxy repository to public group.

2) Calling mvn command with -U ( "mvn jetty:run -U" ) did the trick....!!!

Thanks ! It worked !